# Converting long to int in Java

Tags: java, casting, timestamp, epoch

I'm using System.currentTimeMillis() for getting seconds since the epoch. 
This is an example.

```
 long enable_beacon_timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
 println(enable_beacon_timestamp);
 println(int(enable_beacon_timestamp));      
 enable_beacon(int(enable_beacon_timestamp));
```

And the output gives:

```
 >>1424876956
 >>1424876928
```

So the problem is that there is a mismatch in cast value. What I want is to get the first output the same as the integer.

Can you provide some background why this happen?.

Comment: That code should not compile. There's no `int` method in Java.

Comment: It should be `(int)enable_beacon_timestamp`

Comment: Sometimes, values in long will exceed the limit permited in the integers values. Lookup http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html in order be able to cast correctly your long.

Comment: @KevinAvignon His number example is not exceeding the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` of 2,147,483,647, so it should be fine if he changed it to what I said above.

Comment: @Aradmey That worked! thanks!. Didn't know about that difference.

Comment: Still be aware of Kevin Aivgnon's comment about the fact that long can exceed the maximum value of an `Integer` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast syntax is incorrect. You need also be aware that `long`s can be much bigger that the max value for `int`.

```
int y;
if ( enable_beacon_timestamp > (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE ) {
    // long is too big to convert, throw an exception or something useful
}
else {
    y = (int)enable_beacon_timestamp;
}
```

Try something like this perhaps...

Comment: Good answer but you should also test for underflow (albeit not required in this case).

Comment: Good remark, definitely worth mentioning for reference readers tho System.currentTimeMillis() makes it obsolete to do so in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you could write something  such as

```
try{

   int castedValue = ( enable_beacon_timestamp < (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE )?(int)enable_beacon_timestamp : -1;
   }
catch (Exception e)
{
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java SE 8

1. To avoid doing the calculations yourself, you can use [`TimeUnit#convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).
2. To avoid getting undesirable result due to overflow, you can use [`Math.toIntExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-) which throws an exception if the value overflows an `int`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(seconds);

        try {
            int secondInt = Math.toIntExact(seconds);
            System.out.println(secondInt);
            // ...
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Encountered error while casting.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1621358400
1621358400
```